# How to write test using Mockito or Roboelectric for below code

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I want to write a unit test for the following piece of code using either the mockito or roboeletric test frameworks.

```java
 public static Boolean verifyNetworkAboveLollipop(Context context) {
        SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.
                getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        if (null != subscriptionManager) {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
            if (null != subscriptionInfoList && 0 < subscriptionInfoList.size()) {
                for (SubscriptionInfo info : subscriptionInfoList) {
                    if (null != info && !TextUtils.isEmpty(info.getCarrierName())) {
                        String carrierName = info.getCarrierName().toString();
                        if ("Airtel".equalsIgnoreCase(carrierName)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would suggest mocking the `context` parameter with `mockito`.

Comment: @second I can mock Context as well as Subscription manager but i don't know how to mock SubscriptionInfo List.

Comment: You should use a real list containing either real `SubscriptionInfo` elements (if you can create them easily) or mocks of those. Post what you have tried I'll take a look at correct it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @second, Found a solution in Roboeletric

Comment: @krishna can you share your solution using Robolectric?